# Go to next page with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python

I am new to python, and I have looked at  some examples of scripts already made.
I started my script and it works fine but now I want to add some extras and I would appreciate your help.

```
def listar_videos(url):
    codigo_fonte = abrir_url(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(abrir_url(url))
    content = BeautifulSoup(soup.find("div", { "id" : "dle-content" }).prettify())
    filmes = content("div", { "class" : "short-film" })
    for filme in filmes:
        nome_filme = filme.img["alt"]
        url = filme.a["href"].replace('Assistir ','')
        img = filme.img["src"]
        addDir(nome_filme.encode('utf8'),url,4,img,False,len(filmes)) 

        pagina = BeautifulSoup(soup.find('div', { "class" : "pages" }).prettify())("div", { "class" : "pnext" })[0]["href"]
        addDir('Página Seguinte >>',pagina,2,artfolder + 'prox.png')
```

`IndexError: list index out of range` on this line:

```
pagina = BeautifulSoup(soup.find('div', { "class" : "pages" }).prettify())("div", { "class" : "pnext" })[0]["href"]
```

I alredy try another different code but no sucess.
It's weird because I already used this code in a website Worpress  and it works fine, but this new one gave me this error.
 I need your help guys.

Comment: This error means that you're asking the list for an item in a spot that doesn't exist. Since you're asking for index 0 (ie. the first element in the list) that probably means that `BeautifulSoup(soup.find('div', { "class" : "pages" }).prettify())("div", { "class" : "pnext" })` is returning an empty list. Try splitting this onto multiple lines, and `print` or otherwise test the results you're getting.

Comment: Hi superbiasedman, i already try to split in multiples lines but dont work and print. I have change index 0 for 1,now show me another error :      Error Contents: ('unexpected indent', ('C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Kodi\\portable_data\\addons\\plugin.video.redcouch\\addon.py', 93, 4, "    addDir('Pagina Seguinte',pagina,2,artfolder + 'prox.png')\n"))

Comment: A higher index definitely wont help. Are you getting any results when you try to print different parts? I'm not familiar with `BeautifulSoup` so apologies if my advice is suspect because of that.

Comment: No problem, any help make me more familiar whith pyton :p,

Comment: I continue have the same problem,i will apreciatte any help.